# Render HTML in to React-PDF

Tags: html, reactjs, rendering, react-pdf

I am using React-PDF to generate PDFin my react app.need to render my Html elements into pdf.

something like this -

```
    <Text><p>I have <strong>5</strong> Year <em>experience</em> in&nbsp; <span style='text-decoration: underline;\'>Flowers</span></p></Text>
```

I have **5** Year *experience* in  Flowering

I got this error 
[image: error I got when I tried to add Html element]

need to render this into pdf, is there any method to achieve this ? or any other library

Comment: It may help to include how you're using `react-pdf` in your code. Also please update question to include error message as text and not an image. Screenshots of code and errors are generally not helpful and discouraged.